# ajax does not find a script function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scope

This is the context:

1. I have a script, countrySelect.min.js, that is loaded in the header of a php page (in other positions it doesn't work so assume that this is the correct one)

   ```
       <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>

       <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

       <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/commonFunctions.js'); ?>"></script>

       <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/countrySelect.css'); ?>">  

       <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/countrySelect.min.js'); ?>"></script>

       <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/countrySelectorStyle.css'); ?>">
   ```
2. this script is used inside a function (*initializeLeafletItems*) to apply in the correct positions some country selection drop-down boxes calling its function "*countrySelect*" applied to the objects identified with *$("#country_selector"+temp_offer_id)*

   ```
   function initializeLeafletItems(offers){

       leaflets_info = {};
       var temp_product_info_id;
       var temp_product_info = {};
       var temp_offer_id;
       var temp_default_country_code;

       const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutationsList, observer) {
         [...]
       )};

       [...]

       for(var index in offers){

           if(offers[index]['package_leaflets']){

               temp_default_country_code = offers[index]['defaultCountry'];
               temp_offer_id = offers[index]['id'];

               $("#country_selector"+temp_offer_id).countrySelect({
                   defaultCountry: temp_default_country_code,
                   onlyCountries: offers[index]['countries_list'],
                   responsiveDropdown: true,
               });

               [...]
           } 
        }
   ```
3. this function is called nearly the end of the document, but outside of $(document).ready(function) statement. It works properly, without any mistake.

   ```
   initializeLeafletItems(<?php echo json_encode($offers); ?>);
   ```
4. **the problem**: the same function is called when new elements are added to the page results if the user click on a "SHOW MORE" button. More particularly it is called inside a ajax statement

   ```
   function show_offers(render, from_item, to_item, products_id_list, searchedGeneric, searchedMade, searchedCountries, searchedFormats, searchedCurrency, keywords_id){

       if (render == 'PCRender') {

           $.ajax({
               method:'POST',
               url: ajax_url+'frontController/addRenderScreenOffers',
               data:{  
                             [...]
               },
               dataType:'json',

               success:function(res)
               { 

                   if(res['rendered_PC_screen_offers'] != 'empty'){

                       $("#offers-product tbody").append(res['rendered_PC_screen_offers']);
                       from_item = to_item + 1;
                       to_item = to_item + 10;
                       $("#show_more_button").replaceWith('[...] )">Show More</button>');

                       initializeLeafletItems(res['offers']['offers']);
   ```

In this case, I get this error

```
        Uncaught TypeError: $(...).countrySelect is not a function
```

as if the function was not in the same scope of show_offers function or ajax call. I find this strange; however, when the browser debugger stopped I tried to see the scope that is seen and it seems that the script and its function is already there, look to these screenshots:

[image]
[image]

I have not found many references, for sure not explicit ones, to similar cases, so it will really help to have ideas on it. I read around, in not so similar cases, somebody suggesting to re-load the script inside the ajax call. Even if I don't know it works 'cause I haven't tried yet, I think that since the script is already loaded in the document there should be a way to reference it in both the calls of that function. Is this true?

**UPDATE 12/04/2020**

Logging to the console the object on which it is applied .countrySelect I can observe that in the working case (left in the following image) there is a linked countrySelect plugin, in the not working ones there isn't

[image]

Following a suggestion of the countrySelect author, Mark, I repeated the test on a simpler page and I found that it works both locally (adding an element when clicking a button) and from an ajax call. here following the code of controller and viewer; so I tried also to the not working page to add the simple test adding input elements by clicking a button without any ajax. Even in this case, it doesn't work (but still it works on the elements in the first download of the same page). Any idea? it seems something that gest lost or interact badly on that page.

Here the working code on a simple page (https://www.pharmacomparison.com/frontController/countrySelectTest/)

**controller:**

```
 function countrySelectTest(){

    $this->load->view('countrySelectTest');

}

function countrySelectTestresult(){

    $random = mt_rand(0,999999999);
    $res['html_text']  = '<input type="text" id="country_selector_ajax'.$random.'" name="country_selector_ajax">';
    $res['state']  = 'success';
    $res['random'] = $random;

    echo json_encode($res);
}
```

**viewer**

```
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Country Select JS</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="build/css/countrySelect.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="build/css/demo.css">

                <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/countrySelect.css'); ?>">    
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/demo.css'); ?>">  

                <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/countrySelect.min.js'); ?>"></script>

        </head>
        <body>
        <h1>Country Select JS</h1>
        <form>
        <div class="" id="country">
        <input id="country" type="text">
        <label for="country_selector" style="display:none;">Select a country here...</label>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" style="display:none;">Submit</button>
        </form>
                    <button type="submit"  id="local_test">Local Test</button>
                    <button type="submit"  id="ajax_test">Ajax Test</button>
        <!-- Load jQuery from CDN so can run demo immediately -->

        <script>

        $("#country").countrySelect({
        // defaultCountry: "jp",
        // onlyCountries: ['us', 'gb', 'ch', 'ca', 'do'],
        // responsiveDropdown: true,
        preferredCountries: ['ca', 'gb', 'us']
        });


        </script>

        <script>
        // Make sure we don't run this until after everything else has been loaded.
        // Using the document click handler ensures that everything else is setup first,
        // which ensures we're not cheating and adding our new element before the
        // plugin attaches to form elements the first time.

        $('#local_test').on('click', function(){

        // Step 1: Create a new element from a simulated AJAX request    
        var newInput = $('<input type="text" id="country_selector_local" name="country_selector_local">');

        // Step 2: Add the new element to the page
        $('form').append(newInput);

        // Step 3: Run the plugin on the new element
        $('#country_selector_local').countrySelect({ defaultCountry: 'au' });

        // Step 4: Profit!
        });

        $('#ajax_test').on('click', function(){

                    //the URL return te same content of previous newInput
                    $.ajax({                                                                  

                        url: 'https://www.pharmacomparison.com/frontController/countrySelectTestResult/',  
                        type: "POST",                                                          
                        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',                                      
                        data: {                                                            
                            product_info_id: 'test'                                                                  
                        },  
                        method: 'Post',  
                        dataType: 'json',  

                        success: function(response) {  
                            if(response.state=='error'){                  

                                alert(response.msg);  
                            }                        

                            if(response.state=='success'){  

                                // Step 2: Add the new element to the page
                                $('form').append(response.html_text);

                                // Step 3: Run the plugin on the new element
                                $('#country_selector_ajax'+response['random']).countrySelect({ defaultCountry: 'au' });

                                // Step 4: Profit!  

                            }

                        },



                        error: function(xhr, status, error) {      
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(error);
                            alert("The request returned an error, please alert the site administrators (" + status +").");

                        }    
                    });      
               });


        </script>


        </body>
```

Comment: tryed to add the script inside ajax jQuery.getScript('https://pharmacomparison.com/endUsers/assets/css/countrySelect.css'); it doesn't change anything

Comment: initializeLeafletItems is this function inside  commonFunctions js? if yes then move this after countrySelect js. and also if not then put a console log $("#country_selector"+temp_offer_id).countrySelect({ before this to check whether the element exists or not.

Comment: #Ahmed Sunny thanks for suggestions, but commonFunctions.js is not involved at all. As I wrote countrySelct.js is loaded in the header of the document, initializeLeafletItems near the end of the document so the sequence you are suggesting seems to be respected. I'll try a console.log .. to the $("#country_selector"+temp_offer_id) element you mean, isn't it? I searched manually in the code and I found it but yes I try also with console.og.

Comment: yes, because its a dynamic element, could be the cause, if it doesn't exists, then its not initialized for this countryselect and calling a function on it will give error,  like you use select2 or datatable and call an event on an element that is not initialized for it

Comment: #Ahmed Sunny the element exists and it is found as console.log returns this: "k.fn.init [input#country_selector75]" so the problem is another one as suggested by the error shown by the debugger that point of the fact that the function, not the element on which it is applied, is not found. Any idea? :-)

Comment: hey, there might be issue with your loaded data, for example, temp_default_country_code this could be wrong or null, or the other values, and also the temp_offer_id, try with simple first, just init it with no extra attr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are reinitialising jquery after `initializeLeafletItems(<?php echo json_encode($offers); ?>);` call at the end. Which is reseting the the jquery context and removing the countrySelect function from $.fn

Let me explain

1. Note that you are initialising jquery not twice but three time in the same document.

[image]

and

[image]

see there are they are on line #56, 58 and 5134.

2. Now you are calling

```
initializeLeafletItems(<?php echo json_encode($offers); ?>);
```

on line #4701

[image]

Now what is happening when you run this code on line 4701 country select is attached to one of the jquery loaded earlier and it works. And then jquery is reset and countrySelect is removed from `jquery context` therefor once the page is fully loaded you won't be able to use the countrySelect.

Solution.

1. There should be only one jquery calling (Not mandatory just good practise it'll lower your page load time)
2. Either load jquery at top in `<head>` or somewhere before `<body>` and remove from the line #5134.

### or

load countrySelect.min.js after #5134 and move `initializeLeafletItems(<?php echo json_encode($offers); ?>);` in document.ready

do whatever just load countrySelect.min.js after all of your jquery's are loaded.

FYI: All jquery that you are loading are of same version v3.4.1. So I don't see any specific reason to load it thrice. Correct me if i am wrong.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: #Lalit Sharma thank you very much, I suspected something similar and i was going to start a long procedure to take away piece by piece. You saved me from this long waste of time.

Comment: Glad that it was useful.

Comment: comment #1 is usefull, while working with other extention and if already jquery is implemented then it is causing issue. Thanks Lalit.